# Oracle, 2 procedures avoid deadlock

Tags: oracle, deadlock, procedure

I have two procedures that I want to run on the same table, one uses the birth date and the other updates the name and last name taken from a third table.

The one that uses the birthday to update the age field runs all over the table, and the one that updates the names and last name only updates the rows that appear on the third table based on a key.

So I launched both and got deadlocked! Is there a way to prioritize any of them? I read about the `nowait` and skip locked for the update but then, how would I return to the ones skipped?

Hope you can help me on this!!

Comment: Are you talking about deadlocks or lock contention? Prioritizing won't help to resolve deadlocks

Comment: A few things,  1) please read this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask . 2) please edit your question to show the schemas of the tables in question, and the relevant (or all) the procedure code you are referring to.  We are not mind readers.  A deadlock usually happens if you have two different transactions that are making updates to tables in in different orders.  If you have a deadlock, oracle should have a trace showing what caused the deadlock.

Comment: Why not calculate the age on the fly, when needed? That will get rid of the need for the first proc and the age will always be up to date.

Comment: sorry guys i never ask questions like this, one of my coleagues used my account cause i left my session open and he was having trouble, thank you very much for your answers and i'll update this question with the answer as soon as i talk to him about the solution!

Comment: I think it's a great question and the first I upvoted. It's not schema specific, this type of thing happens in many situations. And it's not database specific.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to lock all rows you will update at once. Doing all updates in a single update statment will accomplish this. Or

```
select whatever from T
   where ...
   for update;
```

Another solution is to create what I call a "Gatekeeper" table. Both procedures need to lock the Gatekeeper table in exclusive mode **before** updating the table in question. The second procedure will block until the first commits but won't deadlock. In 11g you can create a table with no space allocated.

A variation is to insert a row in the Gatekeeper. Then lock only that row with select for update. Then you can use the Gatekeeper in other situations.

Comment: I agree on the use of a lock of some sort to deconflict the queries, but I hate the gatekeeper table or row approach. DBMS_Lock is there to do exactly this sort of task with great efficiency and flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that you got locked because the update for all the rows and the update for a small set of rows accessed rows in different orders.

The former used a full scan and reached Raw A first, then went on to other rows, eventually trying to lock Row B. However, the other query was driven from an index or a join and already had Row B locked, and was off to lock Row A when it found it was already locked.

So, the fix: firstly, having an age column that needs to be constantly modified is a really bad idea. Perhaps it was done to allow indexing of age, but with a correctly written query an index on date of birth will let you find the same records just as quickly. You've broken normalisation rules and ended up coding yourself a deadlocking application. Hopefully you are only updating the rows that need to be updated, not all of them regardless -- I mean, that would just be insane.

The best solution is to get rid of that design flaw.

The not so good solution is to deconflict your queries by running them at different times or by using DBMS_Lock so that only one of them can run at any time.

Comment: I like your solution better. Only downside is DBMS_LOCK is not installed by default.

Comment: It's installed, but access has to be granted. Simply a matter of privileges.